# Información de grupos signalr

Tags: c#, mvc, signalr

Estoy trabajando en mvc 4.5 y me gustaría saber si en signalr hay alguna manera de obtener un listado de grupos que hay creados o de usuarios conectados y a que grupos están asignados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si has leido articulos como ser

[Working with Groups in SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups)

[Mapping SignalR Users to Connections](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections)

entonces conoceras que eres tu quien mantiene los grupos y usuario conectados a objetos en memoria que agregan o quitan al usuario segun la accion que ingresa al `Hub`

Si analizas el segundo link veras en el titulo "Single-user groups" algo relacionado a lo que estas buscando, en realidad envian un mansaje al grupo del usuario, pero como en la clase que administra las conexiones tendras esa info